# Bash: How to convert an array-like-string to array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an array-like-string  `'[ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ]'` and need to convert it to a bash array. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Looks like a JSON array.

Comment: ^^ Or python list :)

Comment: What is the source of this array-like string? (I ask because JSON/JavaScript arrays, Python arrays, Perl arrayrefs, etc., all have somewhat different edge-cases, so it would be best to write something with the right type in mind.)

Comment: `$ line=[ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ]
  $ modline=${line//[,\"\[\]]/}
  $ arr=($modline)
  $ echo ${arr[0]} ${arr[1]} ${arr[2]}`

Answer (score 3):

As you know, arrays are declared in bash as follows:

```
arr=(one two three elements)
```

So let's try to tranform your input into a bash array. Without parsing the input, this might be very error prone and due to the use of eval, considerably insecure when variable user input would be processed.

Nevertheless, here's a starting point:

```
t='[ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ]'
# strip white space
t=${t// /}
# substitute , with space
t=${t//,/ }
# remove [ and ]
t=${t##[}
t=${t%]}
# create an array
eval a=($t)
```

When run on a console, this yields:

```
$ echo ${a[2]}
tag3
```

Comment: For simple data, this could work. But for a bit more complicated data, like spaces or commas within array elements, this would fail. If the data is obtained from unknown source, you should not generally trust it.

Answer (score 0):

The source format is similar to `python` list.
Using `python` for intermediate processing:

```
$ src='[ "tag1", "tag2", "tag,\" 3" ]' # With embedded double quotes, spaces and comma for example.
$ IFS=$'\n' bash_array=($(python <<< 'a='"$src"$'\n''for t in a: print(t)'))
$ printf "%s\n" ${bash_array[@]}
tag1
tag2
tag,"3
```

Comment: Note that this still has the risk of [code injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) in python process.